# core.js:6237 ERROR TypeError: this.form._updateTreeValidity is not a function

Tags: html, angular, typescript

Why do I get this error using dynamic forms?

I got this error and found there much same questions, but any of them wasn't the solution to mine.

This is my HTML:

```
<form [formGroup]="newPreferForm" class="example-form">
  <div *ngIf="!noCriterion">
    <span class="example-list-section">
      <div>
        <div *ngFor="let criterion of c.controls; let i=index">
          <div [formGroup]="criterions">
          <mat-checkbox-group formControlName="check">
            <mat-checkbox  *ngIf="unApprovedCriterion[i].criterionNameOfOthers" 
              [disabled]="existCritereion[i]">
              {{unApprovedCriterion[i]. criterionNameOfOthers}}
            </mat-checkbox>
            <mat-checkbox  *ngIf="!unApprovedCriterion[i].criterionNameOfOthers"
              [disabled]=" existCritereion[i]">
              {{unApprovedCriterion[i]. criterionNameOfMe}}
            </mat-checkbox>
          </mat-checkbox-group>
        </div>

      </div>
    </div>
    </span>
    <div>
      <button (click)="updateCriterions()">save</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

The definitions of the dynamic form and it's controls in the type script is:

```
export class AddCriterionComponent implements OnInit {
 



  newPreferForm: FormGroup;
  get p() { return this.newPreferForm.controls; }
  get c() { return this.p.criterions as FormArray; }
 
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {

    this.newPreferForm = this.formBuilder.group({
      criterions: new FormArray([])
    });

      for (let i = this.c.length; i < this.numOfNewPreferences; i++) {
        this.c.push(this.formBuilder.group({
          check: []
        }))
      }
}
```